# How to Integrate Google Now to iOS App

Tags: ios, integration, google-schemas, google-now

I have to integrate Google Now to iOS apps. Please help me with an idea.I have to find out how to integrate Google Now to my iOS app and Alerts will be shown in Google Now.

Comment: Have you tried any thing from your end? Please post your effort here so that we can suggest.

Comment: I am collecting information. I will provide the information. please wait for my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way to integrate with Google Now is with Google email schemas. You can find the supported Google Now schemas here:

https://developers.google.com/schemas/now/cards?hl=en

Bus reservation and train reservation will also integrate with Google Now:

https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/bus-reservation

https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/train-reservation

It's ideal that your app is transactional. Please note that your email will have to be whitelisted in order to send Google schemas. You can find info on registering here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google

If you would like to do some testing on triggering Google Now cards, you can use the following Apps Script tutorial (using your personal Gmail account):

https://developers.google.com/schemas/tutorials/apps-script-tutorial

If you post more information on what your iOS app does, I can help you determine which markup will help you achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Franco, I am developing home automation iOS app, I need to integrate Google assistant to make iOS app works using voice(It need to works well from background and foreground). For instance: The voice command I need to integrate inside Google assistant is "Turn on hall light". Is this is possible using google assistant inside iOS.